# When you upload files larger than 2GB in Ajax form it is an error in PHP 5.3.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, php-5.3

When you upload files larger than 2GB in Ajax form it is an error.

Javascript:

```
$(document)
    .off("click", ".submit-button-selector")
    .on( "click", ".submit-button-selector", function(){
        var form = $("#form");
        var data = new FormData(form.get(0));

        $.ajax(form.attr("action"), {
            async       : true,
            xhr         : function()
            {
                XHR = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(XHR.upload)
                {
                    // ...
                }

                return XHR;
            },
            method      : 'POST',
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            data        : data,
            dataType    : 'json',
            success     : function(response)
            {
                // ...
            },
            error       : function()
            {
                // If the file is larger than 2GB, it be in this process.
                alert("System Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Server side PHP is 64 bit.

The error log is not out on the server side.

.htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 3012M
php_value post_max_size 3020M
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value max_execution_time 1200
```

I want to know whether this problem is server-side or client-side.

Is this script wrong?

Or, 2GB or more is impossible in the script on this way?

Or, simply one of the server-side problem.

---

EDIT:

It is ok in my local environment. (PHP 5.3.10)

But it doesn't work in PHP 5.3.3 on other web server.

```
$_FILES['file']['error'] ===> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
$_FILES['file']['size'] ===> 0

echo phpinfo();

    upload_max_filesize 3012M
    post_max_size   3020M
    memory_limit    512M
    max_execution_time  1200
```

I have set the file size to 3GB, but it seems to be an error.

It would be impossible more than 2GB in PHP5.3.3?

---

EDIT:

I sent a 2.1GB file but PHP output alert message(validation) that it was more than 3GB. (PHP 5.3.3)

```
    upload_max_filesize 4096M
    post_max_size   4120M
```

It was same results even if it raises limit size. 
(exp: it was more than 4GB...)

??? In fact, it is a completely different point of issue...?

Comment: That is a server limitation. Normally every web server have some limitation on the request size, usually something like a few megabyte by default. There may be other limitations as well, for example if the upload is stored as a file, the file system might not be able to create larger files than that.

Comment: Thank you. It is not a problem of client-side. But an error log is not output... I'll check the server-side.

Comment: Displaying the error from the server may help to pinpoint the reason: `error: function(xhr, stat, err){ alert(stat + ' ' + err); }`.

Comment: chunk uploading can get you around server side upload limitations

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I checked the server-side. I've add a description.

Comment: Have you [**Googled**](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%202gb%20file%20limit) this?